# What is difference between jaxb-impl and EclipseLink-moxy?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb, eclipselink

I was updating java 11 to java 17. i was getting some error in jaxb-impl and i googled and find another jar `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy` which works well with `jakarta.xml.bind-api`.

Can anyone tell me what is difference between jaxb-api and `org.eclipse.persistence.moxy`??

Is both of them are implementation of `jakarta.xml.bind-api` specification? can i still use jaxb-impl with `jakarta.xml.bind-api` with version above 4.0.0?

Comment: No idea, but I'm also interested in the answer